# mount: realpath <PATH>: no such file or directory

Tags: mount, osx, nas

I'm attempting to mount a NAS drive locally, but am having trouble:

```
mount -t smbfs //user:password@nas/path ./tmp
```

Produces

> mount: realpath /Users/user/tmp: No such file or directory

For context, I'm running macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

What am I missing, here?

Comment: Have you made sure you have a directory `./tmp` created already, as the mount point?